# I am trying to simplify the following C# code but if I use a variable instead of a hard value for the transform it doesn't execute

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, transform

Im using transform.translate to move my game object, the code works fine with a hard coded value (provided i make sure to add f to the end of the float) but when I give it a variable to take that same value from the code doesn't seem to execute, nor does it freeze my unity.

I've tried making the variable a float via (float)Xstep, this results in nothing happening when W is pressed.
I modified the code, originally it was setting the 'original X' from the X meaning that everytime X ticked down, orig X did aswell, which while the code did nothing when W was pressed, wasn't an intended result.
I don't believe there is a difference between `(float).25` and `.25f` but if there is I haven't found anything on the documentation as to what the equivilent of suffixing an f does

```
//Original code
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
            StartCoroutine("stepNorth");
        }
    }
    IEnumerator stepNorth() {
        var x = 4;
        while (x > 0)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(0, .25f, 0);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.25f);
            x = x - 1;

        }
    }

}
```

```
//new code using variable
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) {
            StartCoroutine("stepNorth");
        }
    }
    IEnumerator stepNorth() {
        var origx = 4;        
        float Xstep = 1 / origx;
        var x = origx;
        while (x > 0)
        {
            gameObject.transform.Translate(0, (float)Xstep, 0);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds((float)Xstep);
            x = x - 1;

        }
    }

}
```

The end goal of this code is to make a system of movement for a 2d topdown game, made with tiles. The sum of each mini step has to equal one, so that the game object ends up in the center of a tile any time they move. I wanted to simplify this to use variables so that I could test different amounts of "frames" for it more easily.

Comment: 4 is an int, 1 is an int, so it calculates 1 (int division) 4, which is 0, and stores it into Xstep.  You should use `float orgix = 4f;` and `float Xstep = 1f / origx;`

Comment: I'd like to thank you for your extremely quick reply, You actually answered my question before I managed to delete it as I had finally stumbled upon it by dumb luck and fiddling.

Comment: the `f`s are actually not really neccessary. It's enough to have `float orgix = 4;` or `var orgix = 4f`. Later it already knows that it's a `float` and will use the float devision.